# What is the appropriate translation for 'energy'?

Tags: translation

There are many times when I want to tell someone that I don't have enough energy to do something. These are close but not exactly what I want:

我太累。 I'm not too tired, I just don't have as much energy as I used to do what I want to do (like play basketball for 8 hours straight).

我的能力不够。Here, it's not that I don't have the ability to… I can do that, I just don't have the energy to do that (like play basketball for 8 hours straight).

Other contexts where I would like to use this phrase:

- "I have other responsibilities, so I don't have the time or energy
  to sit beside you and manage you."
- "The players aren't lazy, they
  just don't have enough energy to keep up with the other team."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The translation of `energy` to Chinese is really a tricky one, or very "context sensitive". I will try to give example one by one.

1. **体力 Body(Physical) Power**

   > 我太累。 I'm not too tired, I just don't have as much energy as I used to do what I want to do (like play basketball for 8 hours straight).

   ```
   [繁] 我太累, 體力不夠了,不復當年啊。
   [简] 我太累, 体力不够了,不复当年啊。

   Enerygy ->  体力   body(physical) strength / body energy
               不够了 no enough / run out

               不復   not as (good as)
               當年   years ago / in the past
   ```

   So `我的能力不够` should be `我的体力不够`.

   The following example fall in the same usage

   > The players aren't lazy, they just don't have enough energy to keep up with the other team.
2. **精神 Will Power / Brain Power**

   > I have other responsibilities, so I don't have the time or energy to sit beside you and manage you.
   >
   > [繁] 我有其他事情要處理, 沒有那麼多時間精神跟在你後面管著你。
   >
   > [简] 我有其他事情要处理, 没有那麼多时间精神跟在你后面管着你。

   ```
   事情要处理  things that have to be taken care of / responsibilities (责任)
   精神       energy / will power (mental state related)
   ```
3. **PS**

   `体力` is always referring to physical/body strength/state. As `体` mean body.

   `精神` can be referring to mental state only or both.

   ```
   [繁] 他今天精神很好
   He look good today.
   He is in good shape today.
   ```

   `精力` can refer to both physical or mental state, or both at the same time. Mostly interchangeable with the above two.

   > [简] 我太累, **体力** 不够了,不复当年啊。
   >
   > [简] 我太累, **精力** 不够了,不复当年啊。
   >
   > [简] 没有那麼多时间 **精神** 跟在你后面管着你
   >
   > [简] 没有那麼多时间 **精力** 跟在你后面管着你

Comment: Thanks for doing it in 简体字 in addition to 繁体字. I was confused at first but I realized the two were the same sentence just using different orthographies.

Comment: Added [繁][简] prefix. This is a learning experience for me. :) Happy New Year!!

Comment: 麼 = 么 in simplified

Comment: @B.D Yes, the conversion website I use is not good enough, have to find a better one.

Comment: translate.google.com should work fine?

Answer (score 5):

In general, `精力` is the word for human energy as opposite to tiredness. `时间和精力` (time and energy) is indeed an idiom in Chinese.

> "I have other responsibilities, so I don't have the time or energy to sit beside you and manage you."
>
> 我还有别的事，没有时间和**精力**坐在你旁边伺候你。

When referring to sport stamina, `体力` is more accurate.

> "The players aren't lazy, they just don't have enough energy to keep up with the other team."
>
> 队员们不是懒惰，而是**体力**不如对方。

When referring to vigorous personality or lifestyle, the general word is `活力`. Some certain phrases containing `精力` like `精力充沛`/`精力旺盛` has similar meaning, but not `精力` itself.

> "He is always full of energy."
>
> 他总是充满**活力**。